SQR's output is tab delimited. We are converting to new vendor. Need to tell them how to replicate the file. What does $char_tab = chr(9) mean?
What positioning should result from $char_tab = chr(9) in SQR on an output file?  Here is a portion of the write statement:  WRITE 1 FROM record_type:4 $CHAR_TAB $DETSEQ:25 $CHAR_TAB $SUMSEQ:25 $CHAR_TAB         $today_date:10 $CHAR_TAB.
I have tried calculating the spaces between the output data and found many that do not coincide with the number of characters defined for the tab character.

chr(9) writes a single character.  The number of spaces depends on what you're viewing the file with.  The editor (like notepad or notepad++) puts its own number of blanks per its definition.  Try to view it with a hex editor and you will see a "09" in that position.   Additionally, what you are seeing is a tab-delimited output file that can be imported into Excel.  Open it with Excel and use Text to Columns on the Data section of the ribbon.  Select tab characters.  You could probably tell the vendor to write a comma-delimited file which the users can just double-click to open in Excel.

Thank you for your response, cardmagik.  Indeed what you said about Excel is true; I copied some rows into Excel and it broke on the tab character so each field got a new cell.  Our goal is just to tell the new software service provider how to format the file so when existing vendor receives it, their existing process will be able to read and process it.  Sounds like we just need to tell them the data fields need to be tab-delimited and it should be good.  I was seeing extra spaces when viewing the output file that had me worried!  Thank you again for taking the time to explaing this.
